# Django Admin: "Save as New" ignores GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, django-admin, save-as, generic-foreign-key

We have a model A that can be edited in Django Admin. Model B is linked to A via a GenericForeignKey and the linked B instances are displayed together with A in an inline formset.

Now when "save as new" is enabled and used, the copy of the A instance does not have any linked B instances, which is what I would have expected. With regular foreign keys at least it works like this.

Is it a bug in Django or expected behavior? Is there a way ro achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it like this :

```
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  save_as = True

def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    if '_saveasnew' in request.POST:
        for formset in formsets:
            if formset.__class__.__name__ == 'ModelBFormFormSet':
                instances = formset.save(commit=False)
                for instance in instances:
                    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="app", model="modelA")
                    instance.object_id = form.instance.id
                    instance.content_type = content_type
    return super(ModelAAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
```

Not sure if it's the best way to do it tho. But It works.